# Microsoft Graph API and events start and end dates

Tags: timezone, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with the Graph API and trying to create events using the C# `Microsoft.Graph` API. Let's assume to have the following `Microsoft.Graph.Event` objects:

```
{
  Subject = "A Title",
  Body = new ItemBody(),
  Start = {
    DateTime = "2022-10-24T00:00:00",
    TimeZone = "W. Europe Standard Time"
  },
  End ={
    DateTime = "2022-10-25T00:00:00",
    TimeZone = "W. Europe Standard Time"
  },
  IsAllDay = true,
},{
  Subject = "B Title",
  Body = new ItemBody(),
  Start = new DateTimeTimeZone {
    DateTime = "2022-10-28T13:30:00",
    TimeZone = "W. Europe Standard Time"
  },
  End = new DateTimeTimeZone {
    DateTime = "2022-10-28T16:45:00",
    TimeZone = "W. Europe Standard Time"
  },
  IsAllDay = false,
}
```

They are successfully written into my calendar trough twice call to:

`await _graphServiceClient.Users[emailAddress].Events.Request().AddAsync(graphEvent);`

and I see:

[image]

and

[image]

which is the expected behaviour.

Querying the API with the filter `"start/dateTime ge '2022-10-24T00:00:00'"` I get just `B Title`, `A Title` is missing. Furthermore the start and end dates are wrong, I get `2022-10-28T11:30:00.0000000` and `2022-10-28T14:45:00.0000000`.
If I edit the query to `"start/dateTime ge '2022-10-23T00:00:00'"` I get both, the dates of `B title` are the same (wrong), but the ones of `A Title` ar correct `2022-10-24T00:00:00.0000000` and `2022-10-25T00:00:00.0000000`.

I expected that `B Title` has `2022-10-28T13:30:00.0000000` and `2022-10-28T16:45:00.0000000`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call list events endpoint you can specify request header `Prefer: outlook.timezone="<time-zone>"`. If not specified, those time values are returned in UTC.

Example:

```
var events = await _graphServiceClient.Users[emailAddress]
    .Events
    .Request()
    .Header("Prefer","outlook.timezone=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"")
    .GetAsync();
```

I guess that with the correct `outlook.timezone` header your query will return also `A Title` and correct time values.

References:

[Calendar list events - request headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-headers)